# addOnCompleteListener is Unchecked and crashes app

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-markers

I have this code:

```
// Using this method to center MyLocation as default location when app is started
    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    try {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        } else {
        final Task location = mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation();
            location.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location!");
                        Location mLastLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                        // mLastLocation = location;
                        if (mCurrentLocationMarker != null) {
                            mCurrentLocationMarker.remove();
                        }

                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        markerOptions.position(latLng);
                        markerOptions.title("My position");
                        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.emptyicon));
                        mCurrentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location is null");
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

the line: location.addCompleteListener is marked as unchecked by Android Studio and it crashes the app. So I have to make it "checked" in somehow. 
This happened after the latest update patch for Android Studio.

How do I solve this?

Comment: could you show the cmplete uncheched warnng?

Comment: getLastLocation can return null: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#getLastLocation()

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
final Task location = mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    location.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
```

to this:

```
final Task<Location> location = mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    location.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
```

Comment: Will try this later today! Thnx for answer!

Comment: When I added Task<Location>, it came a new unchecked warning started at next line (this, new OnCompleteListener() {

Comment: I just tried to run the app in Andy and now it worked, tho it still has this second warning about unchecked OnCompleteListener

Comment: After pasting the code into Android Studio and looking at the warning myself, I deduced that all you need to add is `<Location>` to your `OnCompleteListener`. See my latest edit.

Comment: Aaah, I didnt see that you had put the Location there as well! :)

Comment: It crashed after adding the second <Location>

Comment: What's the stacktrace look like?

Comment: The stacktrace is the same as logcat? In logcat I found this lines 04-12 pkg='com.android.providers.settings' uid=10039
04-12 18:54:19.911 10912-10922/? E/jdwp: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
04-12 18:54:19.911 10912-10922/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-12 18:54:19.911 10912-10923/? I/AndroidRuntime: NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_1' failed
04-12 18:54:20.211 10937-10947/? I/AndroidRuntime: NOTE: attach  and it was just rolling and repeating...

Comment: After another try this showed up in logcat  at com.example.admin.where_am_i.MapsActivity$1.onComplete(MapsActivity.java:160)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

Comment: It should show a crash log in red when you get the crash; that's what you want to look for in the logcat.

Comment: That second one is in red from logcat!

Comment: It seems pretty unlikely that the second one is related to your crash, though. What I would do is get up to the point right before the app crashes, clear the logcat, and then trigger the crash. That way, most of the text in the logcat will probably be relevant to the crash.

Comment: Hi again! When I open the project it just rolling and rolling in the logcat. Then When I try the app in Andy, it comes to a part with a lot of red texts. There was three files with errors.  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) : at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137). Donnu whats wrong in these files.

Comment: Hi! I solved this by using the onSuccessListener instead of onCompleteListener.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

I would comment if I had 50+ rep.

Anyway, you can continue using

```
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>(){
});
```

by, adding to what @nope4561759 said, adding `<Location>` to Task argument on onComplete() overridden method like so: `public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {…}`

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void getDeviceLocation() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");
    FusedLocationProviderClient mfusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this);
    try {
        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            final Task<Location> location = mfusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            location.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location");
                        try {
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                            //globalLatitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
                            //globalLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please turn on your GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Location not found");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cannot find current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: Security Exception" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

addOnCompleteListener is Unchecked and crashes app solution.

Comment: Please explain your answer.