# My app does not check location.addOnCompleteListener() and crashes

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, location

I am trying to make a location tracking android app. I am getting problem with  **location.addOnCompleteListener** in **getDeviceLocation()** class. Android studio does not check this and the app crashes here. Following is the code i've written...

```
import...

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    Location mLastLocation;
    //FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    public static double longitude = 0.0d;
    public static double latitude = 0.0d;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000;  /* 10 secs */
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000; /* 2 sec */

    public static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    public static final String COARSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        setupContents();
        if (!isNetworkConnected()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "You are offline!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        getLocationPermission();
        //startLocationUpdates();

    }

    public void initMap() {
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        // mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    public void setupContents() {
        btnEnd = findViewById(R.id.btnEnd);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public void getLocationPermission(){
        String [] permissions={Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),FINE_LOCATION)
                ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),COARSE_LOCATION)
                    ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                        mLocationPermissionGranted=true;
                        showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
                        initMap();

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions,LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
             }
            }
            else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions,LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted=false;

        switch (requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length>0){
                    for(int i=0;i<grantResults.length;i++){
                        if(grantResults[i]!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionGranted=false;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    mLocationPermissionGranted=true;
                    showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        mFusedLocationProviderClient=LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        try {
            if(mLocationPermissionGranted){
                Task<Location> location=mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();

                location.addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Location currentLocation= (Location) task.getResult();
                        moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(),currentLocation.getLongitude()),12);
                    }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch (SecurityException ex){

        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng,float zoom){
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,zoom));
    }
    private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser() {
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
        String locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            // Call your Alert message
            Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn on your location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (locationProviders == null || locationProviders.equals("")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        }
           else
               return;

    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
/*        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));*/

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    }

    private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
    }

}
```

The problem arise during debugging is **source code does not match the byte code** after executing this statement  **location.addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener(){**.
The gradle dependencies are:

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
```

stacktrace messages are given below:

```
09-08 22:47:43.485 30955-30955/? E/Zygote: v2
09-08 22:47:43.487 30955-30955/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
09-08 22:47:47.056 30955-30993/com.example.muzammil.maptestingproject E/cr_VariationsUtils: Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/com.example.muzammil.maptestingproject/app_webview/variations_seed_new": /data/user/0/com.example.muzammil.maptestingproject/app_webview/variations_seed_new (No such file or directory)
09-08 22:47:58.366 30955-30955/com.example.muzammil.maptestingproject E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
09-08 22:48:14.641 30955-30955/com.example.muzammil.maptestingproject E/art: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0
09-08 22:48:15.379 30955-30955/com.example.muzammil.maptestingproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.muzammil.maptestingproject, PID: 30955
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.muzammil.maptestingproject.Activities.MapsActivity$3.onComplete(MapsActivity.java:222)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Anyone having the solution help please. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have a crash you have to post the stacktrace.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces

Comment: I've posted it sir

Comment: Have you requested the location permission in your manifest, and have you granted it?

Comment: yes of course sir

Comment: Read here, specifically the last section: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current

Comment: @TheWanderer thanks a lot... it works fine now

Comment: This helps someway.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782739/addoncompletelistener-is-unchecked-and-crashes-app/51613079